# How did Paul became a Roman citizen?

Tags: acts, history, paul, historical-interpretation

In Acts 16:37 we read that Paul was Roman (emphasis mine)

> But Paul said unto them, They have beaten us openly uncondemned, **being
> Romans**, and have cast us into prison; and now do they thrust us out
> privily? nay verily; but let them come themselves and fetch us out.

And in Acts 22:3 we read that he was born in Tarsus (Cilícia)

> I am verily a man which am a Jew, **born in Tarsus, a city in Cilicia**,
> yet brought up in this city at the feet of Gamaliel, and taught
> according to the perfect manner of the law of the fathers, and was
> zealous toward God, as ye all are this day.

How did he become a Roman citizen, if he was born in Tarsus?

---

Related:

- [What do we know about Paul's family?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8025/23182)
- [How did authorities know that Paul was really a Roman citizen?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/39191/23182)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paul was born a Roman citizen:

> And the chief captain answered, With a great sum obtained I this
> freedom. And Paul said, But **I was free born** (Acts 22:28).

This means that a) Paul's father was a citizen and or b) Tarsus was a free city in which every free man born there was a citizen. The commentators are divided on which possibility is preferred:

For example from Ellicott:

> This implies that St. Paul’s father or grandfather had received the
> citizenship; how, we cannot tell. Many of the Jews who were taken to
> Rome by Pompeius as slaves first obtained their freedom and became
> libertini, and afterwards were admitted on the register as
> citizens...The mention of kinsmen or friends at Rome...makes it
> probable, as has been said, that the Apostle’s father may have been
> among them. (Ellicott also points out that at this time in history it
> was the Emperor's prerogative to make someone a citizen)

From Gill's:

> Paul said, but I was free born; being born at Tarsus; which, as Pliny
> says, was a free city, and which had its freedom given it by Mark
> Antony, and which was before the birth of Paul; and therefore his
> parents being of this city, and free, he was born so.

(Note that the significance of Tarsus being a free city is disputed)

In either case, it is very likely that Paul's father was a citizen. We are not told how one of Paul's ancestors obtained this privilege. Per commentaries by Jamieson-Fausset-Brown & by Meyer, possibilities include:

- Some special service to the empire
- Purchase (perhaps legal, perhaps by bribing an official)

Comment: Simple, straight-forward answer. +1.

Comment: @Dottard thank you. You are up quite early today!

Comment: Yes - I have a big day today with relatives, etc so needed an early start.